# 70s novel about government faking an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, aliens, virus

This mid-70s novel was marketed as a mainstream thriller - the USA is falling apart and the president realizes the country needs a common enemy to pull together. So he gathers together a team of specialists to design aliens, a spaceship, and a virus that will make people ill to be "released" by the crashing ship. Turns out the virus will be lethal and people inside the alien creation team struggle to get the word out before the "crash". They are all killed, the crash goes off as planned, the nation begins to rally - but word leaks out about the conspiracy at the very end.

Yeah. A lot like Watchmen.

Anyway, would love a title and/or author so I could track it down again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wasn't there a subplot about material you could eat and get memories or information from it?  And a candy was given to someone at the end, which is the beginning of the leak.

Answer (score 4):

***[Wild Card,](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?839135)*** by **Raymond Hawkey** and **Roger Bingham.** First published in 1974. Here's a cover scan:

[image]

[**ISFDB**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?263152) asserts that this was the first book of a set of three, collectively called "The Presidential Trilogy," but I must warn you to take that with a large grain of salt. I've just been looking at some online summaries of what ISFDB calls the 2nd and 3rd books of the alleged trilogy (titled *Side-Effect* and *End Stage*) and neither one is described as being a sequel to *Wild Card*, nor are their plots described as having *anything to do* with the aftermath of an apparent alien attack meant to unify humans against a common foe. Nor do the character names look familiar. I think each of those three novels has its own cast, facing their own scary problems, in a plot that is wrapped up in a single volume each time, and someone just *arbitrarily decided* that three thriller novels by Raymond Hawkey (he's listed as the sole writer of *Side-Effect* and *End Stage*) should be *called* a "trilogy" for marketing purposes.

Here is an excerpt from the top-rated review [**on Amazon**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345242513) to demonstrate that this is almost certainly the same book from the mid-1970s that you described above. (I simply corrected a couple of typoes.)

> The premise of the story is that, in a time of societal disintegration
> with terrorists setting off nukes in DC and the world descending into
> anarchy, the President and his Science Advisor cook up a plan to
> "rally the world" against a new foe - alien invaders. To do this, they
> assemble an elite team of scientists to create a (fake) flying saucer
> with dead occupants (bio-engineered) and crash this saucer into LA,
> killing 10,000 people. The saucer and its occupants have to be
> scientifically believable, as they expect world experts to study the
> crash site (and verify the alien event). The President hopes this
> event, this external threat, will cause the world to stop destroying
> itself and realize it's us humans against them, the aliens. The book
> details the steps the secret scientific team takes to build a
> believable saucer and occupants.

Note: Used copies of the paperback editions are available cheaply via Amazon, but it seems that no one has ever bothered to convert the text into a Kindle edition.

Comment: Possible dupe https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166024/book-about-impending-revolution-in-us-that-was-thwarted-with-fake-alien-craft-cr

Comment: @Danny3414 Ouch. The other night, I ran across this old question by sheer accident. It was listed in the right-hand column on the screen when I was looking at something else. I thought, "That sounds oddly familiar," and so I did some quick online research to pin down details, and then answered it . . . but it literally *never occurred to me* that someone else might already have asked about such an obscure novel from the 1970s, and been answered correctly, on this site. If it had occurred to me, I would have searched for it first, just to check (and saved myself some trouble). Live and learn!